# NoMethodError (undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass) What is going on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This error is appearing in my heroku logs and I'm not sure what is happening. The app is not functioning correctly and is breaking in many different locations. The weird thing is that this started happening out of no where. No changes have been made in the last 7 days. Everything was functioning correctly on Friday which means this error started occurring sometime over the past 4 days.

Are there any gem dependencies that may have been changed/updated over the weekend that could be causing this error?

Posted is the error

```
Started POST "/advisors/4fbfb0b5ce5da90001000038/intro" for 64.20.10.252 at 2012-11-13 20:24:54 +0000
2012-11-13T20:24:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Cache read: delayed_job_workers ({:expires_in=>1200 seconds})
2012-11-13T20:24:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Cache generate: delayed_job_workers ({:expires_in=>1200 seconds})
2012-11-13T20:24:54+00:00 app[web.1]:  !    DEPRECATED: Heroku::Client#deprecate is deprecated, please use the heroku-api gem.
2012-11-13T20:24:54+00:00 app[web.1]:  !    DEPRECATED: More information available at https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb
2012-11-13T20:24:54+00:00 app[web.1]:  !    DEPRECATED: Deprecated method called from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.31.0/lib/heroku/client.rb:247.
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass):
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/my_company/delayed_job_wrapper.rb:70:in `block in running_workers'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/my_company/delayed_job_wrapper.rb:68:in `running_workers'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/my_company/delayed_job_wrapper.rb:23:in `autostart'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/my_company/delayed_job_wrapper.rb:17:in `feed'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:101:in `block in introduce'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:100:in `each'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:100:in `introduce'
2012-11-13T20:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/advisors_controller.rb:66:in `intro'
```

GEMFILE

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

require 'rubygems'

source 'https://code.stripe.com'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'thin'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

gem "mongo", '1.5.2'
gem "mongoid", '2.4.3'

gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'

gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_mongoid'

gem 'rack-cache'
#gem 'SystemTimer' #Not necessary, but memcache recommends it for performance.
#gem 'memcached-northscale', '0.17.1' #Notice it's memcached, with a D.

gem "heroku"

gem 'json'

#gem 'libxml-ruby'
#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'

gem 'ruby-hmac'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'

gem 'bson_ext'

gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'oauth2'

gem 'oauth'

gem 'stripe'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'mongoid-paperclip'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'fb_graph'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
end

group :test do
  gem "rspec", "2.7.0"
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false

  gem "autotest"
  gem "autotest-rails"
end
```

Comment: The object on which you call the method `text` at the line 70 of `lib/my_company/delayed_job_wrapper.rb` is nil ... that's what the error message is telling you

Comment: There is no method "text" being called in that file.

Comment: please post your controller.

Comment: The error occurs across multiple controllers. It's not specific to any one controller. Again, everything was functioning correctly on Friday and things suddenly broke over the weekend. I have even reverted the application back 4 weeks and the same error is still occurring. This leads me to believe that it has something to do with one of the gems that my application is dependent on?

Comment: Jon -- gotta post code around the line on which the error is occurring -- any code will do; in this example, likely `user.rb` line 101.  The error is confusing, it's not about `text` being wrong.  It's saying an object calling `text` doesn't exist -- it's `nil`.  So look for things that call `text` and then figure out why they are `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Heroku gem was deprecated so I replaced the gem "heroku" in the gemfile with "heroku-api"